# SSIS - How to ignore sequence value for a table using Attunity Oracle Destination

Tags: oracle, ssis, attunity

I am trying to load  data in oracle table. The table has sequence for the primary column (ID). When I try to ignore the column in attunity destination it is throwing error. But it is working in oledb destination.

How can make attunity destination to ignore the primary key field?

Comment: What is the error? Can you recover the query that Attunity created?

Comment: [Oracle Destination [225]] Error: OCI error encountered. ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("RR"."CONTACT"."ID")

Comment: It looks like the table does not have a trigger to populate the ID column with the next value of the sequence. Either write a trigger or instruct attunity to populate the id column by itself.

Comment: But when I ignore the same column using OLEDB destination , it is working...Oracle is generating the sequence automatically

Comment: Try a plain insert in sqlplus, omit the id column. Does that work?

Comment: Yes it is working.... insert into RR(CNC) values (1).this issue is especially working with Attunity Oracle Destination....